# How to copy local wp-content files to Wordpress container using Dockerfile

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile

I have a Wordpress container that I would like to copy local folders (with files) to at startup

I have local files in folders:

```
/html/wp-content/plugins
/html/wp-content/themes
/html/wp-content/uploads
```

I have a Dockerfile with:

```
FROM wordpress

COPY ./html/wp-content/plugins/ /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
COPY ./html/wp-content/themes/ /var/www/html/wp-content/themes
COPY ./html/wp-content/uploads/ /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Although the COPY is succeeding (the build passes), the files are not showing up in these destination folders.

If I change the destination folders to be on any path before /html, eg if I put the destination to be /var or /var/www, then the files copy and I can see them in the container.

I checked out [this old post here](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/115), which mentions that the /html folder is actually mounted as a volume at startup, and so I need to copy the files into this folder first

```
/usr/src/wordpress/wp-content
```

and then at startup these folders will be automatically copied across to /var/www/html/wp-content/. (This would explain why copying directly does not seem to work)

I tried that too, and while my local folders are indeed copied into these folders (I can see them in the container), they are then not copied across to /var/www/html/content at startup!

1. Is it possible to copy the local files directly into the /var/www/html folders via the dockerfile?
2. If not, how can I ensure that if copying to /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content, the folders will be copied across to /var/www/html/wp-content/ at startup?

(Some posts I've looked through that don't work, as this seems to be particular to Wordpress, and not Dockerfile COPY on its own:)

[Dockerfile copy keep subdirectory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215830/dockerfile-copy-keep-subdirectory-structure)
[Docker is not copying subdirectory into Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60128692/docker-is-not-copying-subdirectory-into-container)
[How to copy folders to docker image from Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789984/how-to-copy-folders-to-docker-image-from-dockerfile)
https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/containers/docker/how-to-host-your-wordpress-site-with-docker/
[Wordpress docker copy theme into exposed folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105505/wordpress-docker-copy-theme-into-exposed-folder)

Comment: [Ronald Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7628376/ronald-johnson) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65235658/12695027) saying "..a misplaced or not placed '/' at the end of a path in apache2.conf or other config file"

Comment: Did you find a solution regarding this and can share? Having same issue myself!

Comment: @FlamurMavraj in the end I changed direction and used a mounted volume instead, which helped slightly with the deployment pipeline. But still unable to find a silver bullet pipeline for wordpress - so I still have to make some changes to production on production itself which isnt great.

Comment: @Scratte the answer must have been deleted, but from what you're saying I dont think that was the problem..

Comment: @leo_cape Yes, it was deleted. I came across it when reviewing. I didn't know if it would be useful or not, so I put the content in a comment. I can remove the comment, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran into the same problem. I wanted to add theme when building the image by using COPY. However, it did not work. This was because I already set my wp-content folder as a volume. It seems you cannot COPY into a volume.

The discussion in the following link helped me realise this:

https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/146

Below I have added my WordPres Dockerfile and docker-compose file. After commenting out the volume everything worked as expected.

I sure hope you do not need it anymore after two years, haha.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/samples/wordpress/

Dockerfile

```
FROM wordpress:latest

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY ./wp-content/ ./wp-content/
RUN chmod -R 755 ./wp-content/
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/db/Dockerfile
    image: new_db_image_name
    container_name: new_db_image_name
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060
  wordpress:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/wordpress/Dockerfile
    image: new_wordpress_image_name
    container_name: new_wordpress_image_name
#    volumes:
#      - wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress

volumes:
  db_data:
#  wp-content:
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. And I think the options will depend on your goal. Since I'm overall new to Wordpress and Docker I didn't have clear goal in mind until I went through all the trouble.

### For Local Theme/Plugin Development

For me I wanted to use Docker for my Wordpress theme/plugin development, so what I ended up doing for that was just to **bind mount** my local theme/plugin folders to those in the container in my compose file using the format `<local_folder>:<container_folder>` for example:

```yaml
wordpress:
      volumes:
            - ./src/themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
            - ./src/plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
```

Though I later found out I could use [@wordpress/env](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-env/) instead which is a wrapper on top of Docker.

### For Production Image

Initial I was trying to do this, but didn't realize this was not what I actually wanted, but I got it to work anyways. What I did was just use a **named volume**. Here's an example only showing the *relevant* parts of the docker compose file.

```yaml
services:
      wordpress:
            volumes:
            - wp_data:/var/www/html
volumes:
  wp_data:
```

Then re-build the image and started the container with `docker compose up --build`.